# The difference between nmap option, scan types and ping options

Tags: nmap

scan types, begin with `-s`, such as `nmap -s* target_host`
ping options, begin with `-P`, such as `nmap -P* target_host`

I have used wireshark and nmap to see underlying actions options -P*.

When I run both command

```
nmap -p9527 target_host
```

and

```
nmap -sP target_host
```

I found that the only distinction is that `-sP` cannot be used with port scan option, such as `-p9525`.

I wanna to clarify, whether both of two option `-s*` and `-P*` are used to detect the liveness of target host.

By the way, my environment is on kali which is running on virtual host. I used tcpdump to catch packets and wireshark to analyze.And I run commands as root user.

Comment: If you run Linux, you can look at it with the command: `man nmap`

Comment: I've answered your question, but it might have been better asked on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: By the way, my environment is on kali which is running on virtual host. I used tcpdump to catch packets and wireshark to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many phases to an Nmap scan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87935/nmap-sn-scan-or-no-scan/87949#87949), and the two that these options refer to are *host discovery* and *port or protocol scan*.

The `-P*` family of options are all [different ways to do host discovery](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html). The default scan (if none of these is chosen) performs host discovery using the best method available. The `-Pn` option tells Nmap to skip this phase altogether. It used to be documented as `-PN`, but we changed it to conform with the other "turn this feature off" options. Before that, it was `-P0`, but there was confusion between that and `-PO`.

The `-s*` family of options are all [different types of port and protocol scans](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html). The default scan is a TCP port scan with either `-sS` or `-sT`, depending on privilege level. The `-sn` option tells Nmap to skip this phase altogether. It used to be documented as `-sP` (for "Ping scan"), but that caused the kind of confusion that you and others have reported.

Comment: Great analysis. Your descriptions is consistent with what I saw when I use nmap, tcpdump and wireshark to analyze underlying mechanism about those -P* options. Indeed, all those -P* are used to check the liveness of the target host. My experiments are done by root user. As you said, the default host scan (if none of these -P* options are specified), 4 host scan packets, ICMP Echo Request(actually normal ping), TCP SYN to 443(HTTPS), TCP ACK to 80(HTTP) and ICMP Timestamp Request are used for detecting target's liveness.

Comment: As you mentioned above, -PN -Pn -P0 will skip the ping phase and probe the port availability directly. But I have not found the difference between them. I never known there was a -PO option.

Comment: @DavidJone There is no difference between `-Pn`/`-PN`/`-P0` - they are aliases. The `-PO` option sends a specified IP protocol packet: `-PO6` sends a TCP packet, `-PO2` sends IGMP, etc. See the `nmap-protocols` file for mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Usually aping scan of some sort is done first, and then the hosts that have been found to be up are scanned for open ports.

You can turn the ping scan off (-Pn).  There are also many types of ping scans, including TCP on an optionally specified port.  Which varieties of scan are availabledepends on whether you have root privileges.  IF you are not root, then ICMP echo ping is not available.

`nmap -p9527 target_host` with no other options will first ping the target, and then scan TCP port 9527.

A ping scan  with sP (i.e. ping only) is only for testing which hosts are up.  The port scan is omitted.  So yeah, it's incompatible with specifying which ports should be scanned.

Comment: First, thanks for your reply. Though I'm a novice for nmap, I wanna understand inner action for various options. I have tested for almost 13 options beginning with -P, such as -PN, -PS, -PA, -PU, -P0, -Pn, -PI, -PE, -PP, -PT, -PB, -PY, -PM. And I found that all these options beginning with -P are used for checking whether the target host is up.  As I read about authority document at nmap community, all these scan options for checking liveness of host are uniformly called "PING Options"

Comment: I have not stepped to analyze options beginning with -s, which you called scan type.  After finishing it, maybe I'll come back to bother you again.